# Strange characters issue while working with csv data and JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing. I have requests placed in csv, like this:

```
/api/empId/2f3a1e77-6577-43af-b9fe-258a082e7c81 0
```

There are multiple such requests.

What I observe is that for first request in the file, request generated by JMeter has some characters inserted in the url which cause requests to fail:

```
localhost:8080/my-base-pathï»¿/api/empId/2f3a1e77-6577-43af-b9fe-258a082e7c81
```

As you can see, 'ï»¿' is inserted. It happens only for first record in the csv file.

Any input would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a text file in UTF-8 with a superfluous **BOM** character (`\uFEFF`) as first file character.
This is an invisible space marking the file as Unicode. It was needed under Windows for Notepad to detect UTF-8 i.o. the current Windows OEM character set.

Save the CSV without BOM. For instance in Notepad++.

You could also try to delete it manually without anything visually.